# How do I Access AppModule Module imports from Lazy-loaded Modules?

Tags: javascript, angular, module, lazy-loading

**How do I Access AppModule imports from Lazy-loaded Modules ?**

My **Angular10** App imports **AngularMaterial and NXTranslate Modules** in to the AppModule.
NxTranslate calls an ApiService to get a large Lookup object of thousands of translations.
This is translated at the initial loading of the AppModule.

The App has multiple lazy-loaded routes that also need to use the AnagularMaterial and NXTranslate Modules in their features.

If I use a **SharedModule to load the Modules then the ApiService is called multiple times**. This is obviously not good.
It should only call the ApiService & AngularMaterial once and be available for all modules.

How do I resolve this? I am struggling.
Thanks.

---

**Update**
(sorry for the long post)
This is the **NXTranslate** implementation - it uses a custom class.

```
import { environment } from './../../../../environments/environment';
import { OSCITranslateService } from './translate.service';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {

localeResourcesUrl =
`${environment.baseUrl}${environment.apiUrl.localeResources}`;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
let  options;
const uri = `${this.localeResourcesUrl}${options && options.key ? 
'/' + options.key : ''}`;

let mapped = this.http.get(uri).pipe(
  map((response: any) => {
    let localeData = {};
    let languageCode = response?.languageVariantCode;

    response.resources.forEach(item => {
      localeData[item.keyName] = item.keyValue;
    });
    return localeData;
  })
);
return mapped;
}
}

@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [
CommonModule,
HttpClientModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
    }
})
],
exports: [ TranslateModule ]
})
export class NxTranslateModule { 

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
}
```

This is the **sharedRootModule** that imports the AngularMaterial & NXTranslate

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
})
export class SharedRootModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule
    };
  }
}
```

In **AppModule** SharedRootModule is imported

```
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SharedRootModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    SharedRootModule
  ]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned about the multiple ApiService instances you might end up with? Provide the ApiService within AppModule only, or even better, use the `providedIn` property right in your service's decorator so it gets injected at application level. (https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedIn)

I would just use a SharedModule that exports the mentioned lazy loaded modules.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that but I am not sure it will work. Will let you know.
The Api service is already set as providedIn: 'root'.
The NXTranslate is using a custom class this is making the API call and causing all the issues.  See the code chunks I have added to the question.